# Wordpress Caching Issue - Users need to Clear Cache First

Tags: wordpress

**i cant figure out what's the problem on our site .. why do the user need to clear cache first, before they can login ..**

**Can anyone help me about this?? Thanks in advance**

Answer (score -1):

you have added any plugin if you already have cache plugin then please set the time to clear the cache after